# Filtering within groupBy(x).agg to create averages on different subsets of the Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aggregate-functions

Normally when I have to make aggregations, I use something like the following code in PySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df_aggregate = df.groupBy('id')\
                 .agg(f.mean('value_col').alias('value_col_mean'))
```

Now I actually want to compute the average or mean on multiple subsets of the dataframe `df` (i.e. on different time windows, for example a mean for the last year, a mean for the last 2 years, etc.). I understand I could do `df.filter(f.col(filter_col) >= condition).groupBy....` for every subset, but instead I would prefer to do this in one 'go'.

Is it possible to apply the filtering within the `.agg(..)` part of PySpark?

**Edit**

Example data for one id looks like (the real data contains many values for id):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the conditions inside a `when` statement, and put them all inside `.agg`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df_aggregate = df.withColumn('value_col', f.regexp_replace('value_col', ',', '.'))\
                 .groupBy('id')\
                 .agg(f.mean(f.when(last_year_condition, f.col('value_col'))).alias('value_col_mean_last_year'),
                      f.mean(f.when(last_two_years_condition, f.col('value_col'))).alias('value_col_mean_last_two_years')
                     )
```

Comment: While the code itself works (no error), it only produces NULL/NONE values. The condition I am using is `f.col(month_integer) >= 25` where month_integer takes values from 1 to 36 (i.e. 3 years time)

Comment: See the edit. It is a picture, I am not very good at creating dummy data, sorry.

Comment: Spark cannot understand commas. You need to replace them with dots. See edited answer.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. That did not help unfortunately. Might it have to do with the fact we are not saying what it should do when the `f.when` condition does not hold? As in this example `f.col(month_integer) >= 25`, what would it do for the <25? In essence it should just work as a filter, but I am not sure if it does do that.

Comment: All values are still NULL, whereas I would expect numbers.

Comment: could you try `df.withColumn('value_col', f.regexp_replace('value_col', ',', '.').cast('double')).show()` and see if there are nulls?

Comment: No nulls there. I actually did your suggestion in a step before to check if the conversion was OK, and it was. Somehow there is something that is not correctly working with the `f.when` part I think.

Comment: Great, the `f.col(...)` did the trick. Thanks so much for bearing with me and solving this.